# How to extend Volley Response (to fix There is no default constructor available in 'com.android.volley.Response')

Tags: android, generics, android-volley

I am working from the Volley training on the Android Developer site trying to implement the Example: GSON Request from here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

When I try and extend Response, I get a message saying `"There is no default constructor available in 'com.android.volley.Response'`

```
public class AlertCountResponse extends Response implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("alertCount")
    private int mAlertCount;
}
```

How can I extend com.android.volley.Response?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend it since it has private constructors.

However if you really need a custom Response class you can compile your own custom volley library. It's quite easy too!

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
```

Now through your fav file browser access `./volley/src/com/android/volley/Response.java` and edit it according to your needs

Then back at the console, finish compiling the library:

```
$ cd volley
$ /path_to_sdk/tools/android update project -p . --target android-21
$ ant jar
```

Once done, copy volley.jar to `YourProject/app/libs/` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Request by creating a constructor that takes (method, url, listener, and error listener), and calling Request's public constructor inside your constructor. Request's public constructor will call the private default constructor.

```
    public MyRequestClass (int method, String url, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
    }
```